# How to avoid download images from web more than one time?

Tags: android, web-services, image, loading

I am displaying image's from web using Image downloading logic from url, I want to image download at first time only, next time onwards don't download image from web, because First time downloaded image store in cache memory so i display image from cache memory, In case does not exits that image in cache memory, will download otherwise don't need download that image from web , How is it possible any body guide me ho to so this.?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are u using any view like gridview ,listview or gallary in this

Comment: @Khan yes i am using custom horizontalscroll view for showing images..

Comment: but have u used gallry for this or imageview in scroll view  i don't clear what u have used only horizontal scroll with which view i think put some code here too

Comment: in the scrollview i am using imageview..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with the solution [**`Lazy loading list with images`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview) because it does the same trick that you require. i.e. download image once, store it in cache and display as and when it requires.

Answer (score 1):

go thorugh this example given at GitHub: https://github.com/thest1/LazyList

Answer (score 0):

store your images in sdcard.check wheather your images exist in sdcard or not if yes simply display those images otherwise download from web and store in sdcard,display from sdcard

Comment: i don't know.But it is not good way to store in cache memory because size cache memory is very low compare to sdcard it is better if you store in sdcard.

Comment: actually i am getting image url's from web instead of images i have to store image url's in SQlite after compare i have to download imges..

Comment: store your urls in database.after storing url's in database read that urls from database one by one and using that urls download image from web and store in sdcard.